# Simple: how can I get this jQuery plugin to work?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I found a plugin that scales and positions an image as background. I'd like to use it but there is no documentation.

Here is the plugin:
http://wearebuild.com/wp-content/themes/build/js/jquery.bleedImage.js

It says: 
*Usage: $('#img').bleedImage*
but I don't know what that means.

How do I get it to use my image with class "bleedImage"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Include the file in your page **after** you've included jQuery itself.
2. When the DOM is loaded, call this:

   ```
   $('.bleedImage').bleedImage();
   ```